When I run it from VisualStudio, HttpClient connects, but it does not connect from IIS
When I run it locally with VisualStudio, everything works normally, but when I put it in IIS on the server, I realized that it cannot resolve the domain because it is waiting there forever.
I don't know whether I need to grant permission from IIS or WinServer2012.
I tried adding a record to the lmhost file. It didn't work.
Note: The page opens in Chrome on the server.(https://app.xxxxxxx.com/)
My code:
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://app.xxxxxxx.com/");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ...........");

string contentText = $@"{{""app_id"":""{_vInfo._id}"",""app_secret"":""{_vInfo._secret}""}}";

using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(contentText, null, "application/json"))
{
    request.Content = content;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);  //<<<---------- Waiting here forever
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string _result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

Event Viewer record:
Event code: 3001 
Event message: The request has been aborted. 
Event time: 15.11.2024 12:47:16 
Event time (UTC): 15.11.2024 09:47:16 
Event ID: 4d45d21891154f469c4ca24420c37d85 
Event sequence: 4513 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-8-133761375015957277 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb\ 
    Machine name: WIN22 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7576 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Request timed out.



Request information: 
    Request URL: https://myweb.com:443/ConnectSvc 
    Request path: /ConnectSvc 
    User host address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 66 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace: 


Custom event details: 


My guess would be that your IIS Application Pool user cannot make network requests. Windows Event log is your friend here to help you finding out what is going on.

@Filburt ; I added the log record. It didn't help much. It shows that it's TimeOut, which we already knew. :(

Well can the server resolve myweb.com and is port 443 open to it? What happens if you do Powershell Test-NetConnection -ComputerName myweb.com -Port 443

The updates I made based on a friend's answer worked. I wish he hadn't deleted the answer. I would consider it valid. Unfortunately, someone gave -1 point and he deleted the answer.
I change it: IIS -> Application Pools -> Advanced Settings
Identity = NetworkService

and I add code base:
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

my problem is solved.

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol You shouldn't be messing with this unless you are on .NET 4.5 or lower. Otherwise you make things worse by preventing newer protocols, as it only limits them, it doesn't add unavailable ones.

The entire industry is moving toward TLS 1.2/1.3 exclusively, so when an answer like this shows the need to turn on insecure old protocol versions it’s not going to help others in the right way. BTW, Windows Server 2012 reached end of life for long, and shouldn’t be used any more.

Both comments are correct.
1- The software was prepared with .NET 4.5. They do not welcome upgrading to the new version.
2- The server's operating system update is not under my control.
Thank you both for your interest. Your comments are correct.
